# Use of ! and %in% operators

Tags: r

I have a `factor` variable with countries. I have to use `!` and `%in%` operators so that I can keep the `"United States"`, `"Switzerland"`, `"United Kingdom"` and transform the rest to `"Others"`. But the code I am using is not working

```
country <- c(rep(x = "United States", 466), rep(x = "United Kingdom", 250), rep(x = "Switzerland", 520), 
             rep(x = "France", 97), rep(x = "Italy", 85), rep(x = "Germant", 39), rep(x = "Canada", 25), 
             rep(x = "Singapore", 2), rep(x = "South Africa", 9))
country

bulk <- c("United States", "Switzerland", "United Kingdom")
if(! bulk %in% country) country <- "Others"
```

I am expecting it to make four categories. United States, Switzerland, United Kingdom, Others. But I don't want the solution out of context of "!" and "%in%"  operators.

Comment: *"But I don't want the solution out of context of "!" and "%in%" operators"* I don't understand what you mean here. What context? Are you looking for a solution that only uses `!` and/or `%in%`?

Comment: You probably should be using ifelse.

Comment: Are you looking for `country[country %in% bulk] <- "Others"`?

Comment: No. it is the reciprocal of it. I want United States, United Kingdom and Switzerland as it is and the rest of the countries as Others.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for a vector:

```
country[!(country %in% bulk)] <- "Others"
```

Solution for a data frame:

```
df<-data.frame(country=country, emptycolumn=NA)
df$country<-as.character(df$country)
df$country[!(df$country %in% bulk)]<-"Others"
View(df)
```

Comment: It is giving the following warning and makes the Other countries as NA.          
  Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, !(data$country %in% bulk), value = c(10L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: My actual variable is in a dataframe.

Comment: You should give fully reproducible examples to avoid this kind of unrelated issues. I have added an example for a data frame, maybe edit your question so readers don't get lost. This is due to the fact that your character is converted to a factor when added to a data frame.

Comment: I suggest you simply add this line of code to your question: `df<-data.frame(country=country, emptycolumn=NA)`

Comment: Yes that is the case. My character vector has been changed to factor. Is there a solution now?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
country[ ! country %in% bulk ] <- "Other"
table(country)
#-------------------------
country
         Other    Switzerland United Kingdom  United States 
           257            520            250            466
```

R accepts logical indices for conditional assignments.

Answer (score 0):

```
country <- as.data.frame(c(rep(x = "United States", 466), rep(x = "United Kingdom", 250), rep(x = "Switzerland", 520), 
             rep(x = "France", 97), rep(x = "Italy", 85), rep(x = "Germant", 39), rep(x = "Canada", 25), 
             rep(x = "Singapore", 2), rep(x = "South Africa", 9)), stringsAsFactors = F)

colnames(country) <- "country"

bulk <- c("United States", "Switzerland", "United Kingdom")

country$country[!country$country %in% bulk] <- "Other"

unique(country)

            country
1     United States
467  United Kingdom
717     Switzerland
1237          Other
```